# Python 3 not reading 'if's correctly

Tags: python

I cannot seem to get my piece of code to work correctly. I am sure there are many different ways in order to get this piece of code working with less lines, but this is the only way I can write code for now while understanding it.

When I use values such as 500 for max cost and "b" for desired_features I am only returned with Scarborough, when I should be returned with: Barcelona, California, Corfu, Scarborough, and Whitby as they all have beaches and cost less than 500.

```
print("INPUT:")

max_cost         = input( "How many coins do you want to? " )

print("""\nDesired holdiday features:
    b = beach
    c = culture
    h = hot
    m = mountains
""")


desired_features = input( "Enter string of first letters of desired features: " ) 

#barcelona
if (max_cost >="320" and desired_features == ("bch","b","c", "h", "bc", "bh", "cb", "ch", "hb", "hc" )): \
    destination_list = "Barcelona"
else:
    destination_list = []

print (destination_list)

#California
if (max_cost >="750" and desired_features == ("bhm" , "b", "h", "m", "bh", "bm", "hb", "hm", "mb", "mh" )):\
    destination_list = "California"
else:
    destination_list = []

print (destination_list)

#Corfu
if (max_cost >="300" and desired_features == ("bh", "b", "h", "hb")):\
    destination_list = "Corfu"
else:
    destination_list = []

print (destination_list)

#Paris
if (max_cost >="250" and desired_features == "c"): \
    destination_list = "Paris"
else:
    destination_list = []

print (destination_list)

#Rome
if (max_cost >="300" and desired_features == ("ch", "c", "h", "hc")): \
    destination_list = "Rome"
else:
    destination_list = []

print (destination_list)

#Scarborough
if (max_cost >="45" and desired_features == "b"): \
    destination_list = "Scarborough"
else:
    destination_list = []

print (destination_list)

#Switzerland
if (max_cost >="450" and desired_features == ("cm", "c", "m", "mc")): \
    destination_list = "Switzerland"
else:
    destination_list = []

print (destination_list)

#Whitby
if (max_cost >="60" and desired_features == ("bc", "c", "b", "bc")): \
    destination_list = "Whitby"
else:
    destination_list = []

print (destination_list)


#    holiday_data = [ ["Barcelona",   320,  ["beach", "culture", "hot"]],
#                 ["California",  750,  ["beach", "hot", "mountains"]],
#                 ["Corfu",       300,  ["beach", "hot"]],
#                 ["Paris",       250,  ["culture"]],
#                 ["Rome",        300,  ["culture", "hot"]],
#                 ["Scarborough",  45,  ["beach"]], 
#                 ["Switzerland", 450,  ["culture", "mountains"]],
#                 ["Whitby",       60,  ["beach", "culture"]]
#               ]
```

Comment: Try `in` instead of `==`?

Comment: Why do you have backslashes in lines with "if"?

Comment: even if leaving your homework to the last second, it's never too late to learn basic debugging skills.

Comment: I think you should be using "desired_features in (..." instead of "desired_features == (..."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you mean == in your tests for beaches, etc.  maybe "in"?:

```
if (max_cost >="300" and desired_features in ("ch", "c", "h", "hc"))
```

Note that lists are defined using brackets, not parentheses, and use the "in" operator, not == to determine if a string is in the list.

Fine, I'm not a tuple-hater, just more used to lists... use tuples if you like (above).

Comment: In this case it is really more suitable to use tuples, as they are immutable and constant tuples use less memory and are faster.
http://www.diveintopython3.net/native-datatypes.html#tuples

Comment: That's fine... I won't argue whether *that's* the first optimization he should be making to this code.

Comment: Well that's a different topic, I agree... I just thought it's a good tip and habit for a experienced (Python) programmer, which I believe you are.

Comment: heh, nope... but thanks.  I'm more of a groovy/java guy.  My Python class from Trey last year kicked in when I saw this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are using this

```
if (max_cost >="45" and desired_features == "b")
```

It returns "Scarborough" because only "Scarborough" has a single desired feature of "b"

For example,

```
 if (max_cost >="450" and desired_features in ("cm", "c", "m", "mc"))
```

Edited to change to tuples :)